# Properly aligning a ListView in react-native

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I have a screen in my `react-native` app where I am showing details of a record. It's a pretty simple screen where on the left column, I have a label describing the item and on the right, I have the value of the item. For one of the values, I have to render a `ListView` and I am not able to properly align it. Below is the sample app on rnplay with the symptoms:

[Sample app on rnplay](https://rnplay.org/apps/BRk--A)

Please run on iOS. Here `ComponentListView` is a reusable component that I am using to render `ListView` and it takes a `component` and `data` as it props and render each entry in the `data` using the passed in `component`. Here the list is `BackupList` and the component to render in each row is `BackupSummary`. If you run the app, you will observe that the backups are not aligned properly. I ran it in the `Inspector` on the simulator and looks like the `ListView` starts from where `Varun Accepted` is seen. I am not sure why. Right now there is just one item in the `this.props.backupContacts` but there could be more. I have tried many different `flexbox` properties such as `alignItems, justifyContent, alignSelf` in order to get it to work with no success.

Please let me know if you know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) inside a View and apply css on View, something like this

```
<View style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <ListView/>
</View>
```

Comment: Tried the same thing myself just now and it worked and came to stack overflow to update the question when I saw your solution. But your solution is correct nevertheless. Do you know why would the `ListView` appear that way without wrapping it inside a `View`? I wanted to know it just for my understanding so that I don't make same mistakes again. Thanks!

Comment: I think its because flex properties like 'JustifyContent' works on child components.